# Where to put Commerce Kickstart translation po file?

Tags: 7, commerce, i18n-l10n

After installing a blank Commerce Kickstart site, I'd like install another language as default for the site.

I can see the language `.po` file to download -> [here](http://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads?project=commerce_kickstart)

Where should I put the `.po` files and how can I enable the new language as default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internationalization process is not unique to Commerce Kickstart; it is the same for all Drupal sites and handled by the *Locale* module.  [The Drupal.org documentation can be found here](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/locale).  (Start with [Install a language](http://drupal.org/node/21145).)

Answer (score 0):

- Enable Locale module
- Install and enable [Localization update](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update)
- Find "Languages" in configuration
- Add new language
- If that's not enough, [read the docs](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/locale)

Answer (score 0):

After downloading a commerce_kickstart `.po` file from [here](http://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads?project=commerce_kickstart), import it via:

```
/admin/config/regional/translate/import
```